# Can't login without mounting encrypted $Home from TTY

Tags: 13.04, mount, login, ecryptfs, keyrings

When I try logging in, using the correct password, the screen goes black, it flashes the NVIDIA logo and then takes me back to the login screen.

After trying to restart lightdm, researching .XAuthority and .ICEAuthority, the only solution that worked was to Alt + F1 into TTY1, login and run ecryptfs-mount-private after it gave me some comments on user session keyrings.

I never had to do this before and it broke on the reboot after the latest Ubunutu base upgrade. Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently encountered this problem when upgrading from Lubuntu 12.04 to 13.04, although I (perhaps foolishly) had actually created a new user account with the same name but a different password. I had to login to TTY1 with my new password and run ecryptfs-mount-private using *the old passphrase* before I could get in.

Not sure if this would help in your case, but was able to fix the issue by rewrapping the passphrase ([source](http://goshawknest.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/how-to-change-ecryptfs-home-cripted-filesystem-password-on-ubuntu-and-get-your-files-back/)):

```
ecryptfs-rewrap-passphrase /home/.ecryptfs/$USER/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

After doing this, I have no problems with my signature missing from the keyring; I can simply log in via the GUI without any hassles.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote up, but thank you for your reply. I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu and not encrypting my Home drive during setup. I might try TrueCrypt, because my experience with Ecryptfs has been soured. Thank you, though